# VueJS: Defining 'data' using object literal vs function returning an object

Tags: vuejs2

What are the differences between defining the `data` object in the following ways:

**1. Using Object Literal**

```
data: {
    title: ‘Helly VueJS’
}
```

**2. Function returning object**

```
data() {
    return {
        title: ‘Helly VueJS’
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

> When defining a component, data must be declared as a function that returns the initial data object, because there will be many instances created using the same definition. If we still use a plain object for data, that same object will be shared by reference across all instances created! By providing a data function, every time a new instance is created, we can simply call it to return a fresh copy of the initial data.

The documentation is excellent.